# Kendo UI Trial Limitations

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

Can i know the trial limitations of Kendo .? What happens if 30 days are expired. The only difference is that the trial message will appear after 30days but i can still use all the functionalities.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have an answer now? I'm in the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Currently the Kendo.Mvc.dll assembly stops working after the 30 day trial and starts throwing a server exception. It is possible to extend the trial period on demand by contacting Telerik for few more days.

The Kendo UI scripts remain fully functional.